# toggling dynamically created divs in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two divs with the class names `list_item` and `list_item_menu`.  They are both contained in another div with the class `list_item_container`.  I am able to use the following to show/hide `list_item_menu` when `list_item` is clicked:

```
$(".list_item").click(function() {
    $(this).next('.list_item_menu').toggle();
});
```

This works when the divs are written in the original html, but when the divs are created dynamically, the toggling does not work.  I tried creating them like this:

```
function addListItem () {
var text = $("#new_item_field").val();
$("#list_box").children().last().after(
    '<div class = "list_item_container">'+
        '<div class = "list_item">'+
            text+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class = "list_item_menu">'+
            'notes | due | completed'+
        '</div>'+   
    '</div>'
);
$("#new_item_field").val('');
}
```

and like this:

```
function addListItemToDoc () {
var text = $("#new_item_field").val();

var listbox = document.getElementById('list_box');
var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.className = 'list_item_container';
var item = document.createElement('div');
    item.className = 'list_item';
    item.innerHTML = text;
var menu = document.createElement('div');
    menu.className = 'list_item_menu';
    menu.innerHTML = "notes | due | completed";

container.appendChild(item);
container.appendChild(menu);
listbox.appendChild(container);

    $("#new_item_field").val('');
}
```

but neither way seems to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Look into `$.on()` in jQuery. Basically you want to delegate the events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they are created dynamically, you need to use event delegation and bind the click event to an element that is present at DOM ready:

```
$(".list_item").click(function() {
```

Can become:

```
$("#list_box").on("click", ".list_item", function() {
```

Comment: now to read the documentation and figure out WHY this works.  thanks!

Comment: @mattjulian -- Simple, your click handler is created in the DOM ready function. When you dynamically create elements, they aren't there at DOM ready, so your click handler can't bind to elements that don't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, you should use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('click', '.list_item', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use on instead of click to bind event

```
$("#list_box").on("click",".list_item", function() {
    $(this).next('.list_item_menu').toggle();
});
```